# How do I efficiently read in a single line of user input from the console?

Tags: rust

I recently learned how to read input using `io` from the Rust documentation, but is there any '*simple*' method for reading in console input? My roots are heavily dug into C++, so grabbing input from the console is as easy as `std::cin >> var`. But in Rust I'm doing:

```
for line in io::stdin().lines() {
    print!("{}", line.unwrap());
    break;
}
```

This reads input once, but the for loop seems like a really clumsy way to accomplish this. How can I easily do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`io::stdin()` is in fact a `BufferedReader<>` wrapping `stdin`. As you can see [in the docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufferedReader.html), `BufferedReader` gives a lot of ways to extract content.

You have notably :

```
fn read_line(&mut self) -> IoResult<String>
```

which will try to read a line from stdin (and possibly return an error). A simple code to read an `isize` from stdin would be :

```
let a: int = from_str(io::stdin().read_line().unwrap().as_slice()).unwrap()
```

but it does not any error handling and could easily fail.

A more explicit approach would require you to handle things more cleanly :

```
let a: isize = match from_str(
    match io::stdin().read_line() {
        Ok(txt) => txt, // Return the slice from_str(...) expects
        Err(e) => { /* there was an I/O Error, details are in e */ }
    }.as_slice() ) /* match from_str(...) */ { 
        Some(i) => i, // return the int to be stored in a
        None => { /* user input could not be parsed as an int */ }
    };
```

Comment: Rust is telling me that `txt` does not live long enough to be matched in the next block on your second implementation, how can I get past that?

Comment: never mind fixed, the as_slice() must be moved to the end of the first match statement

Comment: @SyntacticFructose Oh yeah, indeed, good catch ! I'll correct it.

Answer (score 10):

The answers above, as @freinn correctly points out, are now out of date.  As of Rust 1.0, `read_line()` requires the caller to pass in a buffer, rather than the function creating & returning one.  The following code requires Rust 1.26+ (further simplifying error handling).

Note the response is trimmed using `trim_end()`.  This ensures the newline entered by the user will not be part of the response, which would split the greeting across two lines.
Note also the example below is robust in the case the user does not provide a response:

```rust
use std::io::stdin;

type Result<T, E = Box<dyn std::error::Error>> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    println!("Hello, there!  What is your name?");

    let mut buffer = String::new();

    // `read_line` returns `Result` of bytes read
    stdin().read_line(&mut buffer)?;
    let res = match buffer.trim_end() {
        "" => "Ah, well I can respect your wish to remain anonymous.".into(),
        name => format!("Hello, {name}.  Nice to meet you!"),
    };
    println!("{res}");

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: You can replace that type alias with a `std::io::Result`, as it is the same exact thing.

Comment: @Maowcraft Almost, but not exactly the same thing.  https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/error.rs.html#45 shows that specifying the `Error` type is required in `std::io::Result` and the error must be of type `std::io::Error`.  Neither of those conditions is true with the above alias.  While `std::io::Result` is also a fine choice, the alias above can provide additional flexibility in larger projects, if desired.

Answer (score 6):

[`std::io::stdin()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/stdio/fn.stdin.html) returns `BufferedReader<StdReader>`, and [`BufferedReader`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufferedReader.html) implements [`Buffer`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Buffer.html) trait. This means that you can call [`read_line()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Buffer.html#method.read_line) method on it:

```
match io::stdin().read_line() {
    Ok(line) => // do whatever you want, line is String
    Err(e) =>   // handle error, e is IoError
}
```

If you want to read several lines, it is probably better to save `io::stdin()` result into a variable first.

Comment: At the present time, the *read_line* function expects one parameter, a mutable reference to a *String*. For more info click [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line).