# "macro undefined" when reading u8 using scan!()

Tags: input, rust

I read about reading integer input in [How to read an integer input from the user in Rust 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355185/how-to-read-an-integer-input-from-the-user-in-rust-1-0), but I noticed that all the solutions first take a string as input and then convert it to integer. I wonder if there's a way to read an integer directly.

[This page](https://github.com/oli-obk/rust-si#examples) mentions `scan!()` macro but for some reason it doesn't seem to run when I compile the following program using `rustc main.rc`.

```
extern crate text_io;

fn main() {
    let mut a: u8;
    let mut b: u8;
    scan!("{},{}", a, b);
    print!("{} {}", a, b);
}
```

This produces the error:

```
error: macro undefined: 'scan!'
    scan!("{},{}",a,b);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to explicitly say that you want to import macros from this crate:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate text_io;
```

This is written at the very top of the readme, you must have missed it.

To use crates from crates.io, you need to add them to your `Cargo.toml`, for example by adding the following lines to that file:

```
[dependencies]
text_io = "0.1"
```

Comment: Hey! I keep running into your answers today! Welcome to the Rust tag and thanks for your help :)