# How do I use a macro defined in another crate?

Tags: rust

I've seen a couple tutorials to create a Python module using the `cpython` crate but still have errors when building:

```
extern crate cpython;

use cpython::{PyObject, PyResult, Python, PyTuple, PyDict, ToPyObject, PythonObject};

fn add_two(py: Python, args: &PyTuple, _: Option<&PyDict>) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
    match args.as_slice() {
        [ref a_obj, ref b_obj] => {
            let a = a_obj.extract::<i32>(py).unwrap();
            let b = b_obj.extract::<i32>(py).unwrap();
            let mut acc:i32 = 0;

            for _ in 0..1000 {
                acc += a + b;
            }

            Ok(acc.to_py_object(py).into_object())
        },
        _ => Ok(py.None())
    }
}

py_module_initializer!(example, |py, module| {
    try!(module.add(py, "add_two", py_fn!(add_two)));
    Ok(())
});
```

I get:

```
error: macro undefined: 'py_module_initializer!'
```

Where do I get it? I am using Rust 1.12.

---

**UPD**

1. Need to add `#[macro_use]` (as in answers)
2. For other errors - see [examples here](http://dgrunwald.github.io/rust-cpython/doc/cpython/macro.py_module_initializer!.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["macro undefined" when reading u8 using scan!()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396104/macro-undefined-when-reading-u8-using-scan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to declare `cpython` as follows:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate cpython;
```

To be able to use `cpython`'s macros. You can consult [the example in its docs](http://dgrunwald.github.io/rust-cpython/doc/cpython/macro.py_module_initializer!.html).

Answer (score 2):

You must add the [`#[macro_use]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#macro-related-attributes) attribute on the `extern crate` declaration to ask the compiler to bring the macros exported by the crate into your crate's namespace.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate cpython;
```