# How to use macros from re-exported crates

Tags: macros, rust

Crates can re-export crates on which they depend. In this example, the `stm32f103xx-hal` crate does that: `pub extern crate stm32f103xx;`.

In my code, I depend on `stm32f103xx-hal`. Now I want to use the `interrupt!()` macro that is exported by the `stm32f103xx` crate. Do I have to add a `stm32f103xx` crate dependency to my Cargo.toml, or is there a way to re-use the exported definition of `stm32f103xx-hal`?

Note that this is a different problem from simply "how to use a macro from a different crate". Declaring `#[macro_use(interrupt)]` on `stm32f103xx-hal` yields a `cannot find macro 'interrupt!' in this scope` error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a macro defined in another crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945901/how-do-i-use-a-macro-defined-in-another-crate/39945929#39945929)

Comment: Does the `interrupt!()` macro work if you import `stm32f103xx-hal` like this: `#[macro_use] extern crate stm32f103xx-hal;`?

Comment: Found some additional discussion about the now defunct "macro_reexport" feature, which seems very related to the issue at hand: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29638

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to add `stm32f103xx` to your `Cargo.toml`. Here is why:

For example, in the Diesel [`lib.rs`](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/e67985bc0b0d70cdaca917c05a873fdcad253837/diesel/src/lib.rs#L138)

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel_derives;
#[doc(hidden)]
pub use diesel_derives::*;
```

They put `#[macro_use]` on the extern crate line then they use everything from the `diesel_derives` project.

In your case the [`lib.rs`](https://github.com/japaric/stm32f103xx-hal/blob/330c904473dc3a34ef2864166dcbe658992d652a/src/lib.rs#L46) looks like that:

```
pub extern crate stm32f103xx;
```

So the re-export does not specify the use of macros.

This is why you need to add `stm32f103xx` to your Cargo.toml in order to specify the use of macros in your own `lib.rs`.

Comment: That makes sense, though it seems a little brittle to design Cargo like that. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelBöckling what is "brittle" about it? The crate you are using chooses not (or forgot) to export the macros. What do you want Cargo to do about it? Ignore the code as written and just wildly bring in whatever it feels like?

Comment: Well, they can forget to export the macros. The crate already decided about its public API surface, why should another crate that re-exports it have any say in the matter?

Comment: @MichaelBöckling Because what they choose to re-export becomes part of *their* API surface.

Comment: But when the re-exported crate is `optional=true` and comes via feature (and `pub use`), there's no possibility for the re-exporter to `#[macro_use]` it?

Answer (score 1):

The intermediate crate should re-export the macros so that they are available:

mac/src/lib.rs

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! a_macro {
    () => (42);
}
```

inter/src/lib.rs

```
pub extern crate mac;
pub use mac::*; // Re-export the macros
```

ex/src/main.rs

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate inter;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, {}", a_macro!());
}
```

In your case, it's either a bug with the library or they've deliberately decided to not re-export them, so you need to take it up with them. You can choose to directly rely on the underlying crate, but then you open yourself up to having mismatched versions of the crate, leading to annoying errors.

Comment: Shepmaster brings a good point here. In your case, even if the crate `stm32f103xx-hal` would re-export macros from `stm32f103xx`, it would be a best practice to import `stm32f103xx` explicitly allowing you to specify the version you need.

Comment: @KimDesrosiers I believe you've understood me completely backwards. I'm saying that relying on both the re-exported crate and the crate directly is a **bad** idea, due to the version incompatibilities that will occur. You should only use the re-exported code (which you cannot because it's not currently exporting the macro). It is **not** "a best practice to import `stm32f103xx` explicitly" because you cannot control the version that `stm32f103xx-hal` uses.

Comment: I read the last sentence too quick my bad. However, maybe it is not a good practice but in the current situation, we don't have the choice if we want to use macros. Is it possible use two different versions of a crate in the same project? I mean can we alias the re-export where needed and use the other one from our Cargo.toml?

Comment: @KimDesrosiers if you mean "the current situation" as the state of these two specific crates right now, then yes, you have to include the crate both directly and indirectly, to your own future detriment. That's why I encourage OP to file an issue with the crate(s). AFAIK, you cannot specify two versions of the same crate in a Cargo.toml, but you certainly can have multiple versions of a crate in the entire crate dependency graph. See [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423) as one concrete example.

Comment: Definitively open an issue would be the right thing to do.

Comment: `pub use mac::*; // Re-export the macros` is re-exporting everything, is there a way to just re-export the macros and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

This was changed just recently to use the generic import system.

Assuming you want to use the `interrupt!` macro from the `foo`crate, the new way to do it looks like this:

```
#![feature(use_extern_macros)];

pub use foo::interrupt;
```

Note that this is not yet stable, so it is feature-gated behind `use_extern_macros`.