# macro_use equivalent for crate-wide macro use - re-exporting rust-rocket

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am trying to have the rocket crate dependency into a 'common' crate and to re export it for use in my 'test' crate.

This is what I tried:

common:
#lib.rs

```
#[macro_use] pub extern crate rocket;
```

test:
#main.rs

```
#[macro_use] extern crate common::rocket;

#[get("/<name>/<age>")]
fn hello(name: &str, age: u8) -> String {
    format!("Hello, {} year old named {}!", age, name)
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/hello", routes![hello])
}
```

and this:

```
use common::rocket;
```

didn't work.

The solution mentioned in: [How to use macros from re-exported crates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037091/how-to-use-macros-from-re-exported-crates) didn't work either

I am using

```
common = { path = "../common" } #in test crate toml
edition = "2021" #in both crates tomls
rocket = { git = "https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket", rev = "c028d63e5ba275927424397fe9d67cfebdc138ec", features = ["json", "msgpack", "uuid"]} #in common crate toml
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I want to say that the `extern crate` is for an older version of Rust... I think now you can just say `pub use rocket` in your crate's `lib.rs` and it should just work.

Comment: @BallpointBen hi, yes, I've read about it not being used since the 2015 edition anymore, but even when directly using the rocket crate in test, it requires `#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;` to work