# Is there an alternative to read_line that doesn't add anything to the input?

Tags: string, rust, readline

I am making a program that asks a user's age:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("How Old Are You?");

    let mut age = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut age).expect("Failed to get age");

    println!("You are {} years old!", age);
}
```

Once the user enters their age (`8` for example) `read_line` inserts a `'\n'` to what the user inputs. The result looks like

```
You are 8  
 years old!
```

I know I can use something like this to remove the `'\n'` before displaying the age:

```
let age = age.trim();
```

Is there an alternative I could use to read user input **simply** that won't add anything to the variable.

Comment: `read_line` doesn't "add" anything to the input; the user *typed* the Enter key.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain why it isn't already answered by [How to read an integer input from the user in Rust 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30355185/155423), specifically by [this answer using text_io](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30355516/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster Oh that makes so much sense! Thanks, I never thought about it like that.

Comment: @Shepmaster this answered my question