# Fastest idiomatic I/O routine in Rust for programming contests?

Tags: string, parsing, optimization, rust

*My question has been partially answered, so I've revised it in response to things I've learned from comments and additional experiments.*

In summary, I want a fast I/O routine for programming contests, in which problems are solved with a single file and no external crates. It should read in a sequence of whitespace-separated tokens from a `BufRead` (either stdin or a file). The tokens may be integers, floats or ASCII words, separated by spaces and newlines, so it seems I should support `FromStr` types generically. A small minority of problems are interactive, meaning not all of the input is available initially, but it always comes in complete lines.

For context, here's [the discussion that led me to post here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/67391?#comment-515711). Someone wrote very fast custom code to parse integers directly from the `&[u8]` output of `BufRead::fill_buf()`, but it's not generic in `FromStr`.

Here is my [best solution so far](https://codeforces.com/contest/1151/submission/55185471) (emphasis on the `Scanner` struct):

```rust
use std::io::{self, prelude::*};

fn solve<B: BufRead, W: Write>(mut scan: Scanner<B>, mut w: W) {
    let n = scan.token();
    let mut a = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    let mut b = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    for _ in 0..n {
        a.push(scan.token::<i64>());
        b.push(scan.token::<i64>());
    }
    let mut order: Vec<_> = (0..n).collect();
    order.sort_by_key(|&i| b[i] - a[i]);
    let ans: i64 = order
        .into_iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, x)| a[x] * i as i64 + b[x] * (n - 1 - i) as i64)
        .sum();
    writeln!(w, "{}", ans);
}

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let reader = Scanner::new(stdin.lock());
    let writer = io::BufWriter::new(stdout.lock());
    solve(reader, writer);
}

pub struct Scanner<B> {
    reader: B,
    buf_str: String,
    buf_iter: std::str::SplitWhitespace<'static>,
}
impl<B: BufRead> Scanner<B> {
    pub fn new(reader: B) -> Self {
        Self {
            reader,
            buf_str: String::new(),
            buf_iter: "".split_whitespace(),
        }
    }
    pub fn token<T: std::str::FromStr>(&mut self) -> T {
        loop {
            if let Some(token) = self.buf_iter.next() {
                return token.parse().ok().expect("Failed parse");
            }
            self.buf_str.clear();
            self.reader
                .read_line(&mut self.buf_str)
                .expect("Failed read");
            self.buf_iter = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(self.buf_str.split_whitespace()) };
        }
    }
}
```

By avoiding unnecessary allocations, this `Scanner` is quite fast. If we didn't care about unsafety, it can be made even faster by, instead of doing `read_line()` into a `String`, doing `read_until(b'\n')` into a `Vec<u8>`, followed by `str::from_utf8_unchecked()`.

However, I'd also like to know what's the fastest **safe** solution. Is there a clever way to tell Rust that what my `Scanner` implementation does is actually safe, eliminating the `mem::transmute`? Intuitively, it seems we should think of the `SplitWhitespace` object as **owning** the buffer until it's effectively dropped after it returns `None`.

All else being equal, I'd like a "nice" idiomatic standard library solution, as I'm trying to present Rust to others who do programming contests.

Comment: *I'm guessing it has to do* — don't guess, **profile**. What does the profiler say? You are obviously going to be using a profiler if you are so concerned about runtime performance, yes?

Comment: *with the extra `String` and `Vec` allocations, and UTF-8 validation* — none of these have anything to do with `FromStr`. If you started with a static string, presumably your implementation would be just as fast.

Comment: Right, I'm not blaming ```FromStr```. To the contrary, seeing as the ```impl FromStr for i64``` defers to the ```as_bytes()``` representation anyway, I feel this must be possible to do efficiently. It might just be a matter of finding a more efficient way to obtain tokens from a ```BufRead```.
You're right though, I oughta get some practice with a profiler...

Comment: I know nearly nothing about Rust, but I wouldn't favor a program going into an endless loop on unexpected EOF.

Comment: I also would love sth like `cin>>x` or `(f)scanf(..)` in C++. I considered if to maybe rewrite text_io::read into short snippet tailored for programming contests https://github.com/oli-obk/rust-si/blob/master/src/lib.rs

Comment: This looks like some direction to go, but not perfect to me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355185/how-to-read-an-integer-input-from-the-user-in-rust-1-0/57200055#57200055 , I would love sth that reads word by word.

Answer (score 3):

I'm so glad you asked, as I solved this exact problem in my LibCodeJam rust implementation. Specifically, reading raw tokens from a `BufRead` is handled by the [`TokensReader` type](https://github.com/Lucretiel/LibCodeJam/blob/fcd6201e693082d3db334ad53116d2cc00ae1a17/rust/src/tokens.rs#L185-L227) as well as some tiny related helpers.

Here's the relevant excerpt. The basic idea here is to scan the `BufRead::fill_buf` buffer for whitespace, and copying non-whitespace characters into a local buffer, which is reused between token calls. Once a whitespace character is found, or the stream ends, the local buffer is interpreted as UTF-8 and returned as an `&str`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum LoadError {
    Io(io::Error),
    Utf8Error(Utf8Error),
    OutOfTokens,
}

/// TokenBuffer is a resuable buffer into which tokens are
/// read into, one-by-one. It is cleared but not deallocated
/// between each token.
#[derive(Debug)]
struct TokenBuffer(Vec<u8>);

impl TokenBuffer {
    /// Clear the buffer and start reading a new token
    fn lock(&mut self) -> TokenBufferLock {
        self.0.clear();
        TokenBufferLock(&mut self.0)
    }
}

/// TokenBufferLock is a helper type that helps manage the lifecycle
/// of reading a new token, then interpreting it as UTF-8.
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct TokenBufferLock<'a>(&'a mut Vec<u8>);

impl<'a> TokenBufferLock<'a> {
    /// Add some bytes to a token
    fn extend(&mut self, chunk: &[u8]) {
        self.0.extend(chunk)
    }

    /// Complete the token and attempt to interpret it as UTF-8
    fn complete(self) -> Result<&'a str, LoadError> {
        from_utf8(self.0).map_err(LoadError::Utf8Error)
    }
}

pub struct TokensReader<R: io::BufRead> {
    reader: R,
    token: TokenBuffer,
}

impl<R: io::BufRead> Tokens for TokensReader<R> {
    fn next_raw(&mut self) -> Result<&str, LoadError> {
        use std::io::ErrorKind::Interrupted;

        // Clear leading whitespace
        loop {
            match self.reader.fill_buf() {
                Err(ref err) if err.kind() == Interrupted => continue,
                Err(err) => return Err(LoadError::Io(err)),
                Ok([]) => return Err(LoadError::OutOfTokens),
                // Got some content; scan for the next non-whitespace character
                Ok(buf) => match buf.iter().position(|byte| !byte.is_ascii_whitespace()) {
                    Some(i) => {
                        self.reader.consume(i);
                        break;
                    }
                    None => self.reader.consume(buf.len()),
                },
            };
        }

        // If we reach this point, there is definitely a non-empty token ready to be read.
        let mut token_buf = self.token.lock();

        loop {
            match self.reader.fill_buf() {
                Err(ref err) if err.kind() == Interrupted => continue,
                Err(err) => return Err(LoadError::Io(err)),
                Ok([]) => return token_buf.complete(),
                // Got some content; scan for the next whitespace character
                Ok(buf) => match buf.iter().position(u8::is_ascii_whitespace) {
                    Some(i) => {
                        token_buf.extend(&buf[..i]);
                        self.reader.consume(i + 1);
                        return token_buf.complete();
                    }
                    None => {
                        token_buf.extend(buf);
                        self.reader.consume(buf.len());
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation *doesn't* handle parsing strings into `FromStr` types— that's handled separately— but it does handle correctly accumulating bytes, separating them into whitespace-separated tokens, and interpreting those tokens as UTF-8. It does assume that only ASCII whitespace will be used to separate Tokens.

It's worth noting that `FromStr` cannot be used directly on the `fill_buf` buffer, because there's no guarantee that a token doesn't straddle the boundary between two `fill_buf` calls, and there's no way to force a `BufRead` to read more bytes until the existing buffer is fully consumed. I'm assuming it's pretty obvious that once you have an `Ok(&str)`, you can perform `FromStr` on it at your leisure.

This implementation is not 0-copy, but is is (amortized) 0-allocation, and it minimizes unnecessary copying or buffering. It uses a single persistent buffer that is only resized if it's too small for a single token, and it reuses this buffer between tokens. Bytes are copied into this buffer directly from the input `BufRead` buffer, without extra intermediary copying.

Answer (score 1):

I use a struct which stores a `BufRead` and `String`. It can read to a vector or be passed to a macro which returns a tuple of parsed values.

Only one single `String` allocation is made.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, BufRead, BufReader, BufWriter, Write};
use std::str::{FromStr, SplitAsciiWhitespace};

struct Read<T: BufRead> {
    buf: T,
    line: String,
}

impl<T: BufRead> Read<T> {
    fn new(buf: T) -> Self {
        Read {
            buf,
            line: String::new(),
        }
    }

    fn line(&mut self) -> SplitAsciiWhitespace {
        self.line.clear();
        self.buf.read_line(&mut self.line).expect("Failed read");
        self.line.split_ascii_whitespace()
    }

    fn next_arr<U: FromStr>(&mut self) -> Vec<U> {
        self.line()
            .map(|s| s.parse().ok().expect("Failed parse"))
            .collect()
    }
}

macro_rules! scan {
    ( $read:expr, $( $type:ty ),* ) => {{
        let mut iter = $read.line();
        ($(
            iter.next()
                .expect("No next")
                .parse::<$type>()
                .expect("Couldn't parse")
        ),*)
    }}
}
```

This simple approach allows for little boilerplate and a short, clear syntax:

```rust
fn main() {
    // Open inputs and outputs
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open("in.txt").unwrap());
    let mut read = Read::new(stdin().lock()); // or file
    let mut out = BufWriter::new(stdout().lock());

    // Read different types from one line
    let (a, b, c, d) = scan!(read, bool, f32, u8, String);

    // Read a vector from one line
    let arr: Vec<i64> = read.next_arr();

    // Write output
    writeln!(out, "{} {} {} {}", a, b, c, d).unwrap();
    writeln!(out, "{:?}", arr).unwrap();
}
```