# How are there faster solutions to integer addition in Rust?

Tags: rust

The leetcode problem `Sum of Two Integers` reads

`Given two integers a and b, return the sum of the two integers without using the operators + and -.`

However, I *did* use the `+` operator and my solution was just `a + b`.

My submission was slower than 10% of submissions and used more memory than 21% of other submissions - is this just other people doing the same thing and getting more lucky on the benchmarks or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: What are the types? If they're `i32` or `i64` then you can't beat `+`. If they're some bignum data structure, then `+` is creating a (potentially significant) temporary value, and you may be able to outperform it by mutating `a` in place, i.e. `a += b`.

Comment: Both i32, interestingly if you do `a += b; a` the results are better in terms of runtime but worse in memory usage

beats 100% in runtime speed, beats only 58.6 in memory usage, strange

Comment: This question should be on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ and not here, but the "close" option doesn't come up with that as a suggested option.  Either way, ask there please.

Comment: my question got locked on codegolf.stackexchange.com and I was told to post on here 0_0

Comment: The other solutions may be using [faster IO routines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449027/fastest-idiomatic-i-o-routine-in-rust-for-programming-contests) to read the integers from stdin (or the input file) and to write the answer to stdout (or the output file).