# Is there a way to check that the user entered an integer with text_io's read!() macro?

Tags: rust

I want to check that a user entered an integer. If they didn't, I want to redirect them back to the input question:

```
println!("Place Your Chip");
let mut y_col: usize;

loop {
    y_col = read!();
    // Check if user entered in a integer or not
    if y_col < 1 || y_col > 6 {
        println!("Column space is 1 to 6");
        continue;
    } else {
        y_col -= 1;
    }
    if game.check_column(y_col) {
        println!("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tThe column you choose is full");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: No, if you use read and enter a letter, you get `thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Parse("q", "__try_read_var__")',`

Answer (score 1):

The point of [`read!`](https://docs.rs/text_io/0.1.7/text_io/macro.read.html) is to handle errors by killing the thread so that the caller doesn’t need to worry about them. That’s why [`try_read!`](https://docs.rs/text_io/0.1.7/text_io/macro.try_read.html) exists:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate text_io; // 0.1.7

fn main() {
    let mut y_col: Result<usize, _>;

    y_col = try_read!();
    match y_col {
        Ok(v) => println!("Got a number: {}", v),
        Err(e) => eprintln!("Was not a number ({})", e),
    }
}
```

```
$ cargo run
123
Got a number: 123

$ cargo run
moo
Was not a number (could not parse moo as target type of __try_read_var__)
```