# User input macros

Tags: rust

I am running Rust rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04) on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit and I am using CLion with the Rust plugin.

I was following the advice of [@coder3101](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7309666/coder3101) at [How to read an integer input from the user in Rust 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57200055/7884305)

The code coder3101 suggested is:

```
    #[allow(unused_macros)]
    macro_rules! read {
        ($out:ident as $type:ty) => {
            let mut inner = String::new();
            std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut inner).expect("A String");
            let $out = inner.trim().parse::<$type>().expect("Parsable");
        };
    }

    #[allow(unused_macros)]
    macro_rules! read_str {
        ($out:ident) => {
            let mut inner = String::new();
            std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut inner).expect("A String");
            let $out = inner.trim();
        };
    }

    #[allow(unused_macros)]
    macro_rules! read_vec {
        ($out:ident as $type:ty) => {
            let mut inner = String::new();
            std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut inner).unwrap();
            let $out = inner
                .trim()
                .split_whitespace()
                .map(|s| s.parse::<$type>().unwrap())
                .collect::<Vec<$type>>();
        };
    }
```

And then coder3101 suggests the following code to use the macros: (I numbered the lines for reference in this post)

```
   fn main() {
       read!(x as u32);                // (1) - this works as expected 
       read!(y as f64);                // (2) - this line causes errors on input 
       read!(z as char);               // (3) - this line causes errors on input 
       println!("{} {} {}", x, y, z);
    
       read_vec!(v as u32);            // (4) -- this works as expected 
       println!("{:?}", v);
   }
```

I am able to use -- read!(x as u32) to successfully read single u32 integer values.

I am able to use -- read_vec!(v as u32) to successfully read a vector of u32 integer values.

However, when I try to use lines (2) and (3) I get the following error at run-time:

```
    1
    1.02
    thread 'main' panicked at 'Parsable: ParseFloatError { kind: Empty }', src\main.rs:34:5
```

I also get similar errors when I try to enter a char at (3) (here, I commented out line (2) before running the code

```
    1
    b
    thread 'main' panicked at 'Parsable: ParseCharError { kind: EmptyString }', src\main.rs:35:5
```

Is there a specific way to input/type the f64 and char values on the command line that I am missing?  Or, has something changed with the newer version of Rust that is causing issues with these macros?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and ran it without making any changes and it worked for me, is there something else that you have which isn't shown?

Comment: After your reply, I realized this code works on the command line, as expected, when using cargo run -- but fails when running this code in CLion.  I will now look for settings in CLion that might be causing the trouble.

Comment: Is there any reason these couldn't just be a function? `macro_rules!` are so seldom worth it and are a lot harder to work with.

Comment: Here is a non-macro version, which should be preferred when possible: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d18615fe6d06c0316e35a27d19acc0f2 -- note that `read_str()` doesn't trim anymore since that returns a slice. `read_str_trimmed()` is the replacement. With this you'd say something like `let x: u32 = read_as();` or `let x = read_as::<u32>();`

Comment: Would you please include a main function in the playground code you posted to illustrate how to call your functions?  The code compiles using your latter syntax -- let x = read_as::<u32>() -- but each different type fails during run-time with the error -- thread 'main' panicked at 'Parsable: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src\main.rs:20:29 -- which is the line read_str().parse::<T>().expect("Parsable")

Comment: @AlexReynolds It looks like the input wasn't a valid digit, then. The playground doesn't support stdin.