# How can i read vector? i need to sum many of values, what quantity i dont know

Tags: rust

```
use std::io::{stdin, Read};

fn main(){
   let mut nums= Vec::new();
   stdin().read(&mut nums[..]).expect(" ");
   println!("{:?}", nums)
}
```

and o needso that when entering 1 23 123, the compiler outputs [1, 23, 123]

i try to do size for vector:

```
use std::io::{stdin, Read};

fn main(){
let mut nums = vec![0; 10]
stdin().read(&mut nums[..]).expect(" ");
   println!("{:?}", nums)
}
```

`limits the size of my vector and outputs some nonsense`

Comment: The `read()` method on `stdin()` reads raw bytes. If you enter characters or digits, you'll get the UTF-8 representation (or whatever other encoding your terminal is using).

Comment: If you want to read numbers, you will have to read a string with the digits first, convert it to a number and handle any potential errors. See [How to read an integer input from the user in Rust 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355185/how-to-read-an-integer-input-from-the-user-in-rust-1-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read line");

    let nums: Vec<i32> = input
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|num| num.parse().expect("Not an integer"))
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", nums);
}
```

This code will read a single line from the standard input, split it into whitespace-separated parts, attempt to parse each part as an i32, and collect the results into a vector. If you enter 1 23 123, it will correctly output [1, 23, 123].

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the problem.. and if it's not difficult for you, I would like to ask something else, could you show me how to filter values that are multiples of 5 from the resulting vector and save them in a new vector? I tried to do it and made a mistake.. I'm not asking you to edit my code, I'm just asking you to show me how you would do it, I want to see the code of a knowledgeable person/// Please excuse me if I'm distracting or taking up time!!!!!

Comment: No problem.

`let multiples_of_five: Vec<i32> = nums.into_iter().filter(|&x| x % 5 == 0).collect(); `